# Why aren't I getting One Bullet One Hit?

Tags: android, collision-detection, andengine

In my collision detection code, bullets are deactivated once they have been involved in a collision:

```
for(int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++){
    //check for collision
    if(bullets[i].isActive() && bullets[i].getSprite().collidesWith(enemies.get(j).getSprite())){
    
        //remove bullet  
        removeBullet(i); //bullet is deactivated here, .isActive() will return false
        
        if(enemies.get(j).damage(1)){
            // --snip--
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The only place bullets are deactivated is in this section of code. The only place they are activated is when they are created.

Despite this a bullet will inflict damage multiple times. `removeBullet()` triggers an explosion animation, and this plays multiple times. What could be going wrong?

#### Update

Here's `removeBullet()`

```
private void removeBullet(int i){
    if(bullets[i] == null) return;
    bullets[i].deactivate();
    makeSmallExplosion(bullets[i].getSprite().getX(),bullets[i].getSprite().getY());
    bulletPool.recyclePoolItem(bullets[i]);
    bullets[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: Post the removeBullet code, can't help really with what you have posted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one thread may be running? Alternatively it might not be a problem with removing the bullet. But there are multiple bullets at that position and/or enemies?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how threads work in AndEngine, but the delay between first hit and subsequent hits can be large in relation to thread timing issues, so I doubt it's that. I've tested with one bullet and one enemy.

Answer (score 0):

Ah AndEngine; I'm actually a Mod on the forum :)

I've wrote this blog post about object pools in case you need to check the way you've implemented yours:
http://c0deattack.wordpress.com/category/programming/andengine/

I wonder if you're recycling the bullet properly?

Comment: I've read that, and it worked great for the ExplosionPool I made for explosions :-) I've pasted my BulletPool implementation at http://pastebin.com/TvveYkkP, it's probably a bit much to post the whole thing here.

Comment: I've had a look at pastebin, all looks fine. I don't think there's much more I can say without seeing the whole implementation, it feels like its Thread related though.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't want to paste *all* my code. Do you know of something that can give me an overview of how AndEngine uses threads?

Comment: Not sure if there is anything documented, I've not seen anything, perhaps some one may have posted in the forum. I learnt just by reading through the source code. I've you've created your own threads then I would look at any UpdateHandlers you might have registered. Failing that I would just debug the whole thing. Sorry can't give you a solution.

Comment: I've posted everything I think could possibly be relevant in a forum post, perhaps you can get more of an insight there.

Comment: Ok, I've actually found out what it is. If a bullet hits an enemy, it is recycled. Immediately it is obtained again to form a new bullet. Its Sprite's location is not updated (as I set a transform on the Body) before collision detection runs again, meaning the newly created bullet registers another hit. Trying to work out how to fix this now...